# MomentJS remove Time from Date Object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am using Moment.js to create a new date object and pushing to an array using the following code.

```
array.push(moment(object[column]).toDate());
```

The value of 'object[column]' is 2015-01-02 before creating the date object.

This array is used to generate a Google Chart using their API

The date becomes the following.

```
Fri Jan 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

I would like to parse it, to use it in the X Axis. I have tried the following but the console starts yelling.

```
array.push(moment(object[column]).toDate().format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
Uncaught TypeError: moment(...).toDate(...).format is not a function
```

I have tried this and the dates are off by months!

```
array.push(moment(object[column], 'MM/DD/YYYY').toDate());
Messed up data -"Wed Aug 15 1 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

**The outcome I am looking for is 1/1/15**
 - Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you calling `toDate()` at all?

Comment: @MattJohnson Thank you for the reply, removing it causes the graph to go blank. I believe it is because the API requires a date object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
moment("2015-01-02").format("MM/DD/YYYY")  === "01/02/2015"
```

Putting it together with the other things you mentioned, you're probably looking for

```
array.push(moment(object[column]).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
```

That pushes a formatted string into your array.  If instead you want a date object, then you would just push the date object:

```
array.push(moment(object[column]).toDate());
```

If it's just that it's not displaying in the chart the way you like, then use a `DateFormat` formatter, as described in [the Google Charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformat).

Comment: Thank you, I ended up going wtith hAxis format that is included with the API, and using convertOptions for the Material conversion. I appreciate the input so I will choose your answer.